# WriteJson override with JSON.NET library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I made a simple `JsonConverter` because I have a page that posts a JSON array which can be of a generic type.

Posting JSON data and converting that to a typed object works fine using the overriden `ReadJson` method in my custom `JsonConverter` class.

I also need to read from the database again and I do that like this:

```
public Element GetElementById(ObjectId id)
{
    return Db.GetCollection<Element>("Elements").Find(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync().Result;
}
```

The above method is called by a `WebApi` method:

```
[HttpGet]
public Element GetElement()
{
    var element = _elementService.GetElementById(new ObjectId("123e4567b4775f1c48bdabcd"));
    return element;
}
```

From there it returns the right object from the database. But after the `return element` then the `WriteJson` json override method is called in my custom `JsonConverter` class. That method looks like this:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I don't need to do anything special in the `WriteJson` method. Because the object that is returned from the database is good. I'd just like to let the `WebApi` convert that object to JSON and all should be good.

Then how do I implement the `WriteJson` method when I don't need to do anything special in it?

Comment: @garryp Not sure what you're trying to say, this is JSON.NET code? ^^ - "Don't use typed objects when using Mongo and Json?" or something amoung those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override [`CanWrite`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_CanWrite.htm) and return false:

```
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
```